# preg_replace variables

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've written the following `preg_replace` function:

```
function my_foo($bar) 
{
  $bar = preg_replace(
    '/\[blah=(.*)\](.*)(\[\/blah)\]/e', 
    '"<a href=\"http://blah.com/$1\" title=\"$2 On blah\">$2</a>"', 
    $bar);
  return $bar;
}
```

So anything wrapped in `[blah=boob]Boo[/blah]` turns into a link: `blah.com/boob`

Now I would like to take `$1` and do something else with it, how would I go about using `$1` or `$2` from that `preg_replace` in other parts of my script?

As always, thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to call a custom function and pass the matches as array. In such a function, you can "export" those matches to access them from other parts of your script.

Answer (score 0):

[preg_match()](http://php.net/preg-match) allows to set an optional parameter, that takes all matches.